# Material-ui SSR Remix example causes styles to be duplicated after hydration, should I de-dupe them?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I've followed the following example: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/remix-with-typescript to set up `material-ui` with SSR on Remix, and I've noticed that after hydration, I get duplicated styles:

[image: Above are the server-rendered style tags, below are the injected style tags]
[image: Duplicate styles for an element]

So I've been thinking if it would be beneficial to delete the server rendered styles after hydration? I came up with a simple solution of adding an attribute to the server rendered styles and then deleting them either in `client.entry.tsx`, or in a `useEnhancedEffect` in the root component, is there a preference, or should I not worry about the duplicated styles?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this link for more details -  [this link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/remix-with-typescript/app/root.tsx)

Try flushing the Server Side Stylesheets. It is a common practice to flush server side stylesheets at once the client side stylesheet is ready in all SSR based ReactJS libraries. So give it a try.

```js
// Only executed on client
  useEnhancedEffect(() => {
    // re-link sheet container
    emotionCache.sheet.container = document.head;
    // re-inject tags
    const tags = emotionCache.sheet.tags;
    emotionCache.sheet.flush();
    tags.forEach((tag) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      (emotionCache.sheet as any)._insertTag(tag);
    });
    // reset cache to reapply global styles
    clientStyleData.reset();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: As I said I am following that example and have that snippet in my code, the styles still get duplicated